# PromQL Module Missing

Tags: go, promql, go-modules

I am trying to use the promql package [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/promql/parser#ParseExpr)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"    
    "github.com/prometheus/prometheus/promql/parser"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
    parser.ParseExpr("foobar")    
}
```

Having trouble importing. This is the error:

> no required module provides package
> github.com/prometheus/prometheus/promql/parser; to add it:
> go get github.com/prometheus/prometheus/promql/parser (compile)

I tried to run `go get github.com/prometheus/prometheus/promql/parser` as suggested but it fails.

> go get: module github.com/prometheus/prometheus@upgrade found
> (v2.5.0+incompatible), but does not contain package
> github.com/prometheus/prometheus/promql/parser

Here is my `go.mod` currently:

```
module foo.com/bar/parser

go 1.17

require github.com/prometheus/prometheus v2.5.0+incompatible // indirect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `go get github.com/prometheus/prometheus@83032011a5d3e6102624fe58241a374a7201fee8` (that commit is the latest release at this point in time, v2.33.4)

The reason this is needed [is that](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/8852#issuecomment-845379029)

> This is a known issue with Go Modules. The semantic versioning of Prometheus versions the behavior of Prometheus as a server, not its code as a library. By changing the module path to v2, we would suggest that Prometheus obeys the contract of Go Modules as a library, but it doesn't, i.e. there are many breaking changes to expect even in a minor release.

[and](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/8852#issuecomment-967795560):

> Prometheus was not intended to be used as a library. Now that has changed, and it is intended to be used as such, even if we do not accept all general-purpose contributions.

The error you are seeing is because `go get` is grabbing an old release `v2.5.0` by default which was released back in 2018 and does not include the `parser` package. This happens because the versioning scheme used by Prometheus does not align with that assumed by Go.

See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/8852) for additional info.